# Jnlp Java Web Start Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, ant, jar, manifest, jnlp

I am working on an existing project that target upgrade from java6 to java8 ,but when I deploy all my jar to server, it works fine if the client machine is run in java6. but for the java8, it fail to launched by the jnlp which caused by

```
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
```

After search from google, I do learn some of the rules on how to use the manifest file.

I try to sign all my jar with

```
jarsigner -keystore myKeys -storepass changeit XXXX.jar
```

and export the myKeys as a cerf file and then import to the client machine then it can successful launch in JRE6 even without asking the security question.

But for Java8, it fail to launch with class Not found even the cerf is imported, And I found that it maybe I miss some security attributes of my jar 
Then I follow this post by adding field 
http://www.captaincasademo.com/forum/posts/list/1988.page

```
attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions
attribute name="Codebase" value="*"
attribute name="Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase"value="*" 
attribute name="Caller-Allowable-Codebase" value="*" 
attribute name="Trusted-Only" value="true" 
attribute name="Trusted-Library" value="true"
```

my project actually look like in this structure

```
/lib/spring.jar
/lib/commons.jar
/lib/xxxCommon.jar
client.jnlp(herf to xxxClient.jar)
xxxClient.jar
```

I almost test all pattern in that manifest file such as
xxxClient.jar with trusted-library true
/lib/spring.jar with trusted-library true
or 
xxxClient.jar with all-permissions
/lib/spring.jar with trusted-library true
or
even I remove all security attribute .
And it does fail by the class not found.

I know that the reason(from other post) because the trusted library and untrusted library is loaded by different class loader, so if spring.jar is an untrusted one, it will silently ignored.

Even I mark xxxClient.jar(my project jar) with/not with trusted-library
or spring.jar trusted/not trusted library, those all fail with same statement class not found.

Due to I am working on maintenance duty, I can't make change like class.forName(), Class.getResource() which come from
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html

is that any way that I can success upgrade from JRE6 to JRE8 without code changes? Thank a lot

by the way, my jar manifest attribute is added by ant just like above code and third party jar(spring.jar) i apply jar -ucf to update the inside manifest file.

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Finially my manifest look like this

```
Application-Name: xxxxx-Client
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: true
```

But actually I am not sure is it works or not because the major change is my jnlp file.
My original jnlp file look like this

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" />
  <jar href="XXXX-Client.jar"/>
  <nativelib href="lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
  <nativelib href="lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
  <nativelib href="lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar"/>
  <nativelib href="lib/spring.jar"/>
  ......
```

From official document, I think nativelib or jar is does't matter to my applet.
Who cares is it run in root or not. I modified it to user "jar" and push spring.jar to a higher level

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" />
  <jar href="XXXX-Client.jar"/>
  <jar href="lib/spring.jar"/>
  <jar href="lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
  <jar href="lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
  <jar href="lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar"/>
  .....
```

Then nothing goes wrong!!!! I can't determine why it fixed, or which part is most important. Because the original jnlp is works fine in JRE6 without error.